# Attributes.Add Onclick Event in C# code behind

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two textboxes `tbxProdAc` and `txtbxHowMany`. I would like to write a bit of code in the code behind so that when I enter text in one, any text that may have been in the other is removed.

How would one go about achieving this and in which event should I place it?

I have tried to use:

```
txtbxHowMany.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('tbxProdAC').innerText='';");
```

in the page load event but without success; should this be in the `pre_init`?

As you can probably tell, complete novice at work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, make sure that when the page has been generated that the ID is still "tbxProdAC" if this is a .Net control, the ID would have been changed. In this case you can use a class.

Try the following, - This uses JQuery - you will need to include that

```
txtbxHowMany.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#tbxProdAC').val('');");
```

Add the following to the Head Section of your page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

And you can get the JQuery.Js file from here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery

And Why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308751/why-use-jquery

Comment: Thanks Pino - by saying "you will need to include that" do you mean just adding in the jquery library refer in my source code or actually in the code behind? (apologies for the thick question)

Comment: I've updated my main post, and your not being "thick" by asking. We all need to ask questions! Keep asking its what makes you better.

Comment: Hmmm...I must have done something wrong!

I used the code provided, the page loaded up fine, I entered data into tbxProdAC then clicked on the txtbxHowMany. This brought up an error defined as "Object doesn't support this property or method"

I must have gone wrong somewhere!?! I put the '...attributes.add..' in my c# code behind in the page load event...was that correct or should this go into mymain source code?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Updated main post Val has a lowecase v :)

Comment: I love you and want to have your babies : ) Thank you very, very much, that has helped one hell of a lot...not just for this example but it also now makes sense in my head which I shuold now be able to expand on.

Comment: Best reponse to a question ever!

Comment: Well, I may have to take the babies back off you!
 
Ok, so 

txtbxHowMany.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#tbxProdAC').val('');");

works like a charm.

Yet 

tbxProdAC.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#txtbcHowMany').val('');");

Doesn't appear to work at all.

Now confused...something else must be firing to render the second example useless.

Comment: It might help if I spelt the controlIDs correctly!!! Honestly, I'm not doing myself any favours here!!!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Changes the ID's of the generated controls, so probably your tbxProdAc will have its id changed to something else. You need to run the app once, view source and know the Id of your control and then replace the "tbxProdAc" with the new Id in your

```
txtbxHowMany.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('tbxProdAC').innerText='';");
```

and yes it will work onLoad.

Answer (score 1):

main issue here is that when your control is inside another control (for example a grid) asp.net prefixes the id of your control to keep the id of the control unique, for example the id won't be txbProdAc but it will be Gridview1_txbProdAc or even this:
Panel1_Panel2_gridview1_txProdAc.

if you want to know in code behind which id asp.net will 'give' or 'rename' your control, yo can use the .ClientID  property:
txtProdAc.ClientID  will give you the id you have to use from javascript/jquery.

if you ever place your txbProdAc within another control it will still work because the .ClientID function will always give you the right id for the control in client script.

Michel

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Michel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819808/attributes-add-onclick-event-in-c-code-behind/1820140#1820140) answer, you're event adding should be correct but you need to set the id selector differently as ASP.NET changes the id that gets sent to the client:

```
txtbxHowMany.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').innerText='';", tbxProdAC.ClientID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit to what TheOne have answered, when we view the source of the webpage it'll show the rendered content. where the ID will be different. some thing like this.

```
txtbxHowMany.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbxProdAC').innerText='';")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use the design view, you can just double click your textboxes and it will create these methods for you:

```
    private void tbxProdAc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtbxHowMany_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

then you just have to edit them like this:

```
     private void tbxProdAc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbxHowMany.Clear();
    }

    private void txtbxHowMany_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbxProdAc.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: TextBox..::.TextChanged Event - Occurs when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server.